# Configuring the BIOS before installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, bios

Recently I was asked about whether Ubuntu go on laptop ASUS F552CL-X211H.
Now I would like to know what you want to disable or, conversely, to include in the BIOS to make it work as it should.

Comment: Change UEFI to Legacy in bios.

Comment: Neil, how to do it?

Comment: @DendyCraftMenTV You do not need to do anything with your bios to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Pilot6, Why is that? What could be wrong with this?

Comment: There is no need to turn off UEFI. That's it. And if you have Windows installed in UEFI mode, it will create problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on your specific hardware.

## You need not disable or enable anything in the BIOS / UEFI before installing Ubuntu.

In particular, if you want to boot both Windows 8 or above that came with the computer and Ubuntu **don't mess with your BIOS**. See [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) for more information.

On the other hand, if you plan to completely remove Windows and replace it with Ubuntu, you may change the BIOS to legacy mode. It does not make any difference.

Please read the Ubuntu community documentation on [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) and on [UEFI Booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) for more information.

Hope this helps